# User authentication: can login but cannot authenticate

Tags: php, security, symfony

I'm trying to use symfony authentication, but I can log in, but the profile says authenticate: no.

I haven't use FOS, but program in my own the security file.

Do you know why? I have read that is possible that the serialization problem is.

My User class:

```
<?php

namespace testBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"utilisateur" = "Utilisateur", "eleve" = "Eleve", "moniteur" = "Moniteur", "secretaire" = "Secretaire"})
 */
class Utilisateur implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max = 4096)
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->isActive = true;
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt() {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles() {
        $roles = array('ROLE_USER');
        return $roles;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials() {

    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list (
                $this->id,
                ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username) {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getPlainPassword() {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($password) {
        $this->plainPassword = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive) {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive() {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled() {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
```

EDIT:

security.yml:

```
security:
    providers:
        moniteur:
            entity: { class: testBundle\Entity\Utilisateur, property: username}

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern:   ^/login$
            anonymous: ~
        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: /
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            provider: moniteur
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /


    encoders:
        testBundle\Entity\Utilisateur: plaintext
```

SecurityController:

```
<?php
```

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SecurityController extends Controller {

    public function loginAction(Request $request) {
//        var_dump('asdas');
//        exit;
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
//        var_dump($lastUsername);
//        exit;
        return $this->render(
                        'security/login.html.twig', array(
                    // last username entered by the user
                    'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                    'error' => $error,
                        )
        );
    }

    public function loginCheckAction() {
        // this controller will not be executed,
        // as the route is handled by the Security system
    }

}
```

Comment: Where's your security configuration?